# Negate int using XOR and addition

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, xor

I have to write a method which converts an int value to the same negative int value. For example, if the user types in 5 the method should give back -5.

The whole story is:
The method has a transfer parameter which is either a positive or a negative int. Is it a positive int, we should change it to a negative int. If it is a negative int, do nothing.
It is also hard to check if the given int is positive or negative.

The regulations:

- I'm only allowed to use the arithmetic operation `+` and all the boolean operations. But in this case I know that I have to use XOR.
- It's not about writing the method and all the JAVA stuff. It's just the logic I struggle with.

How can I change a value to its negative value using only XOR and `+`?

**ATTENTION:** 
The only operations allowed are:

`!
^
&&
||
+`

No *, no -, no ~

Edit:
The two solutions from CherryDT and MikeC are working well. Any ideas how to check if its a negative or a positive parameter with the same regulations? I thought this would be the easy part. Then realized it isn't.

Comment: To understand this task, you need to understand that most computers, and most programming languages, store signed integers as [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement), including Java. Now that you know what it's called, you can easily google "[negate two's complement](https://www.google.com/#q=negate+two%27s+complement)" and find many answers.

Comment: You have to use `num < 0` to check for a negative value in Java. It isn't like a C-based language where you can `if (0) ... else`. Or you could add the reversed number and use `== 0`

Comment: Why are those boolean operators even allowed, given that you cannot create any booleans in the first place? Do you actually have more allowed operators? Right shift would also be extremely useful now that we know you really want to implement `abs`

Comment: Please don't deface your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(x ^ -1) + 1`

Explanation: Basically, it's the same as `~x + 1`. `-1` has all bits set, and therefore inverts all bits when XORed with, just like NOT. And since, the other way round, inverting will always give you `-x - 1`, all you need to do is invert and add 1.

Comment: Thank you. But I'm not allowed to use - or ~ .

Comment: @plategt Are you allowed to use `<<`?

Comment: Yes, but it's questionable whether `-` is an operator here or just part of the number `-1`. Knowing the word size, we could also write `0xFFFFFFFF` instead, for example (if it's a dword), then there would be no minus.

Comment: Not bit shifting. Sorry. With that, I had an idea.

Comment: Following up on my previous comment, if the minus (which I still think should be considered part of the constant "minus one") is not allowed, and hardcoding the word size is problematic, this should do it as well: `(x ^ (Integer.MAX_VALUE + Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1)) + 1`

Comment: Thank you and sorry for reading to fast. I don't think I'm allowed to use defined methods. I didn't tell the whole story, cause I thought it doesn't matter. The complete task is: The method has a transfer parameter which is either a positive or a negative int. Is it a positive int, we should change it to a negative int. If it is a negative int, do nothing.

Comment: Hm, there is one thing I'm stumbling upon: you said you may use plus and all boolean operators. You list `&&, ||, !`. But `^` is a bitwise, boolean operator and `&&, || , !` are logical boolean (`&, |, ~` would be bitwise), so what about them? And why can't you use `~` then?  And are you allowed to use `if`s or `?:`?

Comment: I was wondering about this also. But the tutor gave me the hint to use + and ^ . And wikipedia says that XOR is a boolean operator. I think I'm allowed to use if. Otherwise this would be impossible. But I'm not allowed to use = or == . There should be another option to check the values. I think I'm allowed to use all JAVA statements except of functions, methods and all mathematic signs except the mentioned ones.

Comment: So, what about `&`? Is it allowed or not...? It's a bitwise boolean operator like `^` (unlike `&&` which is not bitwise). Because then it would be trivial - the number is negative `if(x & 0x80000000)`

Comment: & is not allowed. But && and || will be. Why 0x80000000?

Comment: Because this is the highest bit in a signed 32 bit integers and is the only bit with a negative value (namely `-pow(2, 32)`), so it has to be set if the number is negative.

Comment: Are you allowed to create new variables?

Comment: Maybe. it won't work with if(x & 0x80000000). I tried this. There must be something different. Don't you think there is a way, same as the negation to check the value?

Comment: OK sorry I forgot that in Java you can't put a number into an if and have it implicitly compared to zero...

Comment: Wait a sec, this means we can't so anything at all! You are not allowed to use any numerical comparator (`==, !=, >, <, >=, <=`), right? So you can't do anything in the if anyway...? (sorry I don't have a Java environment around to test at the moment)

Comment: Thank you to take care so much about this. No. I think i can't use one these. But I can use &&, ||, !, ^ maybe in the if statement. I think we are nearly there. There is just one little check left.

Comment: Hm, honestly, I don't think there is a way to do it. Since (and now I tested it) in Java you can't implicitly convert numbers to booleans, but you also are not allowed to use any operators which would create booleans (such as `==`), there is nothing you could put into an `if` or use in conjuction with `&&` or `||` which wouldn't throw an error "int cannot be converted to boolean" or such. This would mean that `&&`, `||` and `!` are useless - and I'm not sure if it's possible to achieve what we want with `^` and `+` alone.

Comment: Hi again. Thank you so much for trying out. I have the same opinion. I have done it with == now as I think there is no other possibility. If you have the same opinion, which is more qualified than mine in this case I think, I'm ready to discuss this. Lets see if this will be right.

Comment: As said, I don't know any way only with xor and plus. Please, once you got feedback, tell us here what was the outcome of this and what (if any) would have been the right solution, because it sure will be interesting to know!

Answer (score -2):

Here we go

```
public class Test {

     public static void main(String []args){
        int x = 245;
        System.out.println(x);
        x = (~x^x)*x;
        System.out.println(x);
     }
}
```

Comment: Why do you multiply by `x`?

Comment: ~x ^ x gives -1, which can be multiplied by actual number to change the sign

Comment: Question says `+` and boolean operations, not `*`.

Comment: Right. Sorry. I think you missed the part of the question that said only XOR and + are allowed

Comment: ah! my bad. But this is definitely an interesting way to do using only x's

Comment: Thank you. But I'm not allowed to use * and ~ .